# How to call magento module in custom page?

Tags: magento, controller

I have added this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('sales/order/history.phtml')->toHtml();
```

to mypage.phtml, but it is giving

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\puckerimages_cvs\app\design\frontend\default\pucker\template\sales\order\history.phtml on line 41
```

Can anybody tell me how to call core module controller in custom pages

Comment: It seems there is a function getSize() residing under history.phtml and the block you have defined i.e. "core/template" not able to find its definition. That is why error is occurring. Please assign its relevant block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

instead of "*core/template*" use "**sales/order_history**"

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sales/order_history')->setTemplate('sales/order/history.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

I dont know exactly what you were tried to do..Controller is nothing but your url segment. 
If you want get controller from Url use the following code,

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();

Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

If you want get collection of data from your Module use the following code,

```
 Mage::getModel('groupname/classname');
```

or

```
Mage::getSingleton('groupname/classname');
```

Example

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('order', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSort('last_name', 'ASC')
    ->addAttributeToSort('first_name', 'ASC')
;
```

Comment: i want to call a history.phtml in my custom page. but when it get calls it gives fatal error. could you please suggest how can i call history.phtml to other phtml file so that we can use the core functionality of the history.phtml page ?